# Calculating marginal R2 for a mixed effect model with new (predicted) values

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models

I have a mixed effect model trained on one dataset, and then used to generate predicted values for another dataset. How do I obtain the marginal R2 for the new predicted values?

As an example, let's break the sleepstudy data from the lme4 package into two subsamples, keeping participants grouped together:

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(33)
dataA_list <- lapply(split(seq(1:nrow(sleepstudy)), sleepstudy$Subject), function(x) sample(x, floor(.5*length(x))))
dataB_list <- mapply(function(x,y) setdiff(x,y), x = split(seq(1:nrow(sleepstudy)), sleepstudy$Subject), y = dataA_list)

dataA <- sleepstudy[unlist(dataA_list),]
dataB <- sleepstudy[unlist(dataB_list),]
```

I trained a mixed effects model on the first dataset (dataA)

```
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), dataA)
```

Then, I can use that model to generate predicted values from the second dataset (dataB)

```
pred_values <- predicted(model, data=dataB)
```

I can obtain the marginal R2 for the model applied to dataA using the MuMIn package

```
library(MuMIn)
r.squaredGLMM(model)
```

But how do I learn how well the model performed on dataB? I can correlate the predicted values with the actual values, and square it:

```
(cor.test(dataB$Reaction, pred_values)$estimate)^2
```

But this produces an overall R2, which is not ideal for interpretation purposes.

Comment: I think this could be a fairly tough problem. Most of the R^2 machinery that has been built for mixed models focuses on decompositions of the variance within the model, rather than "observed vs explained". This might have to start with a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question to the effect of "has anyone developed a *theoretical* framework/definition for out-of-sample R^2 in mixed/multilevel models?", then come back to SO to find out about implementation.  In the mean time, your predicted vs obs correlation might be about the best you can do ...